# Cannot resolve AppCompatActivity after updationg

Tags: android-studio

in my build.Gradle(app) I updated The appcompat
from

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
```

and now the AppCompatActivity won't work and I even returned the old version but still nothing.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {}
```